# App crashes (Firebase authentication related)

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication

Here's the code -

```
    public class login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button signIn;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private EditText emailID;
    private EditText password1;
    private TextView emailLabel;
    private TextView passwordLabel;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        emailID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFieldEmailID);
        password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFieldPassword);
        emailLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelEmail);
        passwordLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelPassword);

        signIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void loginUser(){
        String email = emailID.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = password1.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            //email field is empty
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            //password is empty
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter your password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //if validations are ok
        //show a progressbar
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    public static final String TAG ="";

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }

                    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
                        progressDialog.setMessage("User has signed in");
                        progressDialog.show();

                    }
                });




    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == signIn){
            loginUser();
        }
    }  
  }
```

> Error that I am getting on starting the application - 01-13
>   17:07:13.543 5027-5058/com.example.kinnari.trial2 D/FA: Logging event
>   (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   engagement_time_msec(_et)=2716,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=-7572526684473257642}] 01-13 17:07:13.734
>   5027-5027/com.example.kinnari.trial2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down
>   VM 01-13 17:07:13.737 5027-5027/com.example.kinnari.trial2
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.kinnari.trial2, PID: 5027
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.kinnari.trial2/com.example.kinnari.trial2.login}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at com.example.kinnari.trial2.login.onCreate(login.java:46)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)  01-13
>   17:07:13.851 5027-5047/com.example.kinnari.trial2 I/zygote: Background
>   concurrent copying GC freed 6839(912KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(124KB)
>   LOS objects, 50% free, 1707KB/3MB, paused 6.740ms total 111.655ms
>   01-13 17:24:04.987 5027-5054/com.example.kinnari.trial2
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the *`signIn`* button before the line:

```
signIn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Because of this, the button always has a null value and that's what is causing your app to crash.

Adding `signIn = findViewById(R.id.yourButtonID);` before the line above will fix your problem. I don't think there's a problem with the rest of your code.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Firebase Authentication.  You just haven't assigned a value to `signIn`, and when you call setOnClickListener() on it, it's throwing a NullPointerException.  Give it a non-null value before calling methods on it.